# Writing log files in disk instead of db in drupal

Tags: drupal, logging, drupal-modules

Is there a way (or a module) to write log files into the disk instead of writing them to db? Because i really don't want my db getting fatter just because log lines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. It's part of the core of Drupal. It's call syslog. However, it logs in the system log file by default.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have some fast disks... you could easily create a bottleneck by doing so. Instead, I would regularly dump the log tables to a file, say using a cron job.

You could add this to a file called `drupal_logs.sh`:

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d")_$(date +"%H%M.%S")
mysqldump -p - -user=username dbname tableName1 tableName1  > /path/to/drupal_$NOW.sql
```

And schedule that to run every 15 minutes by adding the following cron job:

```
15 * * * * /path/to/drupal_logs.sh  > /dev/null
```

And if you're worried about the log files in the database getting to large, you can follow your `mysqldump` command in your `drupal_logs.sh` with a `truncate` command of the exported tables.

Comment: thank you robert, but what i am looking for is writing the log files before it writes to the db. Thanks anyway.